# Reloading view controller when navigation bar back button is pressed in swift 2

Tags: ios, core-data, swift2, reload, viewcontroller

I have three view controllers which in the third one I have a picker view which it store data into core data, and when I press navigation bar back button I want second view controller to refresh it's labels from core data, but I don't know how
Any suggestion ? 
[image]

Comment: Use `viewWillAppear:` event in second view controller

Comment: @markov thanks for comment but what should i do in viewWillApear in second view controller ? fetch the core data or reload view ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use NSFetchRequest() method in viewWillAppear() method in second view controller

Comment: @iPareh thanks for answer In which view controller should i implement this ?

Comment: you should need to implement in second view controller above define method when you press back button in third(picker controller used).

Comment: if you are use table view controller in second view controller then also need to reload data tableview controller self.tableView.reloadData()

Comment: @ipareh I don't use table view controllers it's just an stack view which contains multiple labels. i'm trying to write code when back button is pressed in second view and i'll let you know

Comment: I couldn't make it work, can you write a code which you think it'll works ?